# How to count unique elements in an array without using any other data structures JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, element

I have an array of integers, I need to count the unique elements and their occurrence without using any other data structures thus I'm only allowed to use arrays.

Comment: I suppose you already tried something. What doesn't work?

Comment: sort the array. Iterate. Every time the number changes add one to the count.

Comment: sort the array and then check adjacent elements ...

Comment: As far as I know, arrays are aggregate data structure, so they are data structure

Comment: another hint: you can use auxilliary array if you know that elements are in some small range (e.g., from 0 till 100);

Answer (score 2):

Perform a quick sort on the array, then go through each element, and if the current element is equal with the next, increment a count variable.

When they are different, reset the count variable.

Comment: Also when you are done with one number, increase the index + how many were the same as the variable

Answer (score 0):

quick sort array, then loop through array and if element a and b are equal to each go to next element with variable b and keep doing this and increasing count until they are not equal to each other. once they are not equal make count 1, make a b and increase b to the next element and do it over and over until the end of the array is reached

```
array quicksort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
      int index = partition(arr, left, right);
      if (left < index - 1)
            quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
      if (index < right)
            quickSort(arr, index, right);
}

unique()
{
  array = quick sort(some_array,sum_int,another_int);
  int count = 1;
  int a=0;
  int b=1;
for(int i =0; i< array.length; i++)
   if(array[a] = array[b])
    {
     b = b+1
     count = count +1;
    }
   else
    {
      System.out.println(array[a] + " occurs :" + count + " time")
      a=b;
      i = count + i;
      b = b+1
      count = 1;
     }
}
```

Comment: this is post has been flagged as a low quality answer, please provide some explanation

Comment: so it quick sorts the array then has a counter and an int a which is 0 and an int b whcih i will change to one. then if the array index[a] and index[b] are equal to each other increase count the 1. If they are not equal, then add how many counts there were to i+1 as well as increase a to the end of where the count ended to start at the next number. and keep doing this until the end of the array is reached

Comment: @KickButtowski just curious why this is flagged and other with same code are not?

Comment: just your answer came up but you made it better

Comment: @KickButtowski no worries just was going through the algorithm myself haha you know what they say you can always bet your first algorithm will go wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops. For each element, loop the array again looking for the same element, keeping a count, and "zapping" the occurrences when found (i.e: replace them with a placeholder to be ignored by your logic). Maybe something like this:

```
String[] myArray = {"e1", "e2", "e3", "e2"}

for(s in myArray) {
  count = 1
  for (j = 0; j < myArray length; j++) {
     if (s not null && s equals myArray[j]) {       /ignore zapped elements
        count++             //count occurrences
        myArray[j] = null   //zap. If null is an acceptable input, use another placeholder
     }
   }
   print "Element " + s + " repeated " + count + " times
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution in pseudo-code (which happens to be valid Python):

```
def count_unique(arr):
  arr.sort()
  count = 1
  for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i] != arr[i - 1]:
      count += 1
  return count

print count_unique([1,2,3])
print count_unique([1,2,1])
print count_unique([9,8,8,8])
```

It simply iterates over the sorted array and counts transitions between groups of equal elements.

It does not work for the empty array (returns `1` instead of `0`). I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for the reader.